# Should I add a semicolon after a function definition?

Tags: syntax

should I write the program like this:

```
f[x_]:=x^2; 
g[x_]:=x+2;
```

or should I write the program like this:

```
f[x_]:=x^2
g[x_]:=x+2
```

Which one is good practice, does any of them have side effect?

Comment: No difference that I know, except that you can put multiple pieces of code on one line, when they are separated by semicolons.

Comment: One trivial side effect is that a semicolon affects indentation in the front end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a difference between [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) with or without semicolon, but it usually doesn't matter. The semicolon is actually a [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) which has `Null` as its last element - that's the one that gets returned.

But `SetDelayed` returns `Null`, too. So the results returned with or without semicolon are the same.

An *exception* to this statement occurs when the `SetDelayed` fails, as in the case `2:=1` where I try to assign a value in a forbidden way. Then `SetDelayed` returns `$Failed` instead of `Null`. But if you end the `:=` assignment with a semicolon, then the result `$Failed` is **not** returned, because the `Null` is still the last expression in `CompoundExpression`. Therefore, if you're doing `:=` inside a structure that watches for the occurrence of `$Failed` in the assignment, you can't use the semicolon. Here is a test:

```
Print[2 := 1];
Print[2 := 1;]
```

[image: setdelayed]

In normal usage in the notebook, I don't think there's any reason to use the semicolon after `:=`. However, one more case where I find it safer to use semicolons at the ends of such lines is when the code is not in a notebook but in a text file that may be read on different platforms, where line breaks could potentially be gobbled up so that the semicolon is a safety measure, preventing lines from unintentionally being merged into one.

Comment: Jens, I have marked this question as a duplicate.  Please let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right, I think you covered everything there, and even mentioned `SetDelayed`. I must have overlooked that thread.

Comment: Someone is using M11... ;-)

Comment: @P.Fonseca Yes, don't you love the stylish messages?